# Scroll doesn't work in JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have a `JPanel` inside a `JScrollPane`, where I draw some shapes with `Graphics`.
The problem is when I draw outside the bounds of the panel, the scroll in the scroll pane doesn't work. I have autoresize activated on the `JPanel`.

Any tip?

Comment: Can you post a toy example of your code?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom painted `JPanel` should return a preferred size appropriate for the graphic elements it contains.